# Measuring and comparing 'closeness' of two different clusters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clustering, spatial-cluster

i'm doing a paper for university and i'm having problems with statistical analysis in QGIS (v.3.28). i have two sets of waypoints (nests) from two different years plotted on a beach in QGIS. visually it's very clear that year 1 waypoints (N=10) are far more spread out or less clustered together than in year 2(N=15).

my approach was to use 'mean coordinates' tool to find the center point of each cluster, then measured the distances of each waypoint to its center point for that year with 'distance to hub'. i averaged the distances for year 1 and year 2 and used a simple t-test to compare the two means, but it's not statistically significant, which i thought it would be.

this is fine, but i'm not sure if my methods are reliable or if i can measure this in another, easier, much more accurate way.

Comment: Spatial autocorrelation is a way to measure the clusterness of features. You can use the `Hotspot Analysis` plugin to calculate the Moran's Index which will indicate whether the clusters are random or not.

Comment: @Padmanabha thanks for the reply! im trying to install Hotspot Analysis but qgis is telling me i need to install pysal:
'Couldn't load plugin 'HotspotAnalysis' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysal'' 
i have since learned that to install pysal, i must install pip, which i can't find a straightforward tutorial for. do you know of any tutorial i could follow? thanks again.

Comment: Installation problem will be another question since it is not related to the current one. Ask it in a separate post.